# Obtener JSON remoto método HTTP GET en Android

Tags: java, android, json

Necesito obtener un `json` alojado en la web, necesito algo simple que se conecte al servidor mediante la `url` y compruebe si la petición GET es `200` y devuelva en formato texto el json y si hay un error devuelve `null`.

Iré posteando lo que vaya realizando...

Comment: Usa la libreria Volley, sin duda la mejor opcion.

Comment: Aquí un ejemplo muy claro [de servicio](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/12/consumir-un-servicio-web-rest-desde-android/)

Answer (score 2):

Yo uso la [librería Volley de Android](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html).

Este es un código de ejemplo que tengo, totalmente funcional, en mi app.
Como me pone nervioso demasiado código :), cuando obtengo la respuesta la paso al método `procesarRespuesta()` para procesar allí el JSON.

Para manejar los errores yo uso una clase personalizada llamada `VolleyErrorHelper`, en la cual se manejan los posibles errores que pueda haber y según el error puedes lanzar un tipo de mensaje personalizado. Si te interesa editaré la pregunta agregando también esta clase.

Como ves, con Volley el código queda claro, entendible y fácil de usar, sin tener que acudir a recursos complicados u obsoletos.

```
private static final String TAG = "MiActivity";

//...

String sURL="http://www.example.com";
requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

// Nueva petición JSONObject
jsObjectRequest = 
    new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,sURL,"",
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                procesarRespuesta(response);
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyErrorHelper errorVolley = new VolleyErrorHelper();
                String sError = VolleyErrorHelper.getMessage(error, getApplicationContext());
                Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + sError);
            }
        }
);

// Añadir petición a la cola
requestQueue.add(jsObjectRequest);

//...

//Método para procesar la respuesta (parsear el JSON)

protected String procesarRespuesta(JSONObject jsObject) {
    //Procesar el JSON

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mi propia solución para obtener un `json` remotadamente mediante `HTPP GET` con soporte de parámetros

**Función buildURL**

para armar una url si se le especifica una lista de parámetros

```
public static String buildURL(String url, Map<String, String> params) {
    Uri.Builder builder = Uri.parse(url).buildUpon();
    if (params != null) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            builder.appendQueryParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    return builder.build().toString();
}
```

**Función performGetCall()**

```
public static String performGetCall(String requestURL,
                                        HashMap<String, String> getDataParams) {

        URL url;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            url = new URL(buildURL(requestURL,getDataParams));

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection  = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(15000);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");

            int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){

                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                }

            }
            urlConnection.disconnect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response.toString();
    }
```

**Su uso**

```
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Log.d("json recibido", "read: " + performGetCall("url del json",null));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
```

Comment: Si era una autorespuesta se recomienda publicar la pregunta y la respuesta al mismo tiempo, así no nos esforzamos por responder pensando que tienes un problema. Y... no olvides de marcar la respuesta que ha resuelto el problema. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el siguiente codigo es el que utilizo para mis llamadas GET :

```
public static boolean ejemploHTTPGET()throws IOException,JSONException
{
    try
    {
        String respStr;
        HttpClient httpClient;
        HttpGet del;
        HttpResponse resp;
        JSONObject responseObject;
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        //cargamos la Url en la cual esta almacenado nuestro servicio
        del = new HttpGet("https://api.myjson.com/bins/oqz97");
        del.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        resp = httpClient.execute(del);
        respStr = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());

        //obtiene la respuesta en formato JSON
        responseObject = new JSONObject(respStr);

        System.out.println(responseObject.getString("valida"));
        if(responseObject.getString("valida").equals("true"))
        {
            return true;
        }else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return false;
}
```

el link del webService es la siguiente : https://api.myjson.com/bins/oqz97