# Como podria leer un json devuelto por php multilinea en android

Tags: php, android

Quisiera saber como podría leer este **json** en android, los registros pueden aumentar o disminuir dependiendo del paciente.

```
[{"Paciente_Nom":"Carmen","Paciente_Ape":"Moran 
Espinoza","Fecha_consulta":"2018-02- 
20","Hora_consulta":"11:02:28","Prescripcion":"2 Acetaminofen cada 8 
horas","sintomas":"Dolor de cabeza\r\nFiebre\r\nMalestar al 
cuerpo","otroDiagnostico":"Ninguno"}, 
{"Paciente_Nom":"Carmen","Paciente_Ape":"Moran 
Espinoza","Fecha_consulta":"2018-03- 
15","Hora_consulta":"14:47:39","Prescripcion":"20 Acetaminofen cada 8 
horas","sintomas":"Dolor de cabeza Fiebre Malestar al 
cuerpo","otroDiagnostico":"Ninguno"}]
```

cualquier ayuda es válida.

Comment: Alexander te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizad o intentado, más información, etc**, saludos!

Comment: Recomendaría que uses [`Volley` de Android](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/) para eso. [Aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/61027/29967)  con algunos detalles, y [aquí tienes otro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/50336/29967). Lo más importante en `Volley` es que la petición tiene que ser conforme al tipo de objeto/dato que esperas. En este caso, en lugar de un `JSONObject` (como indica el enlace), tendrás que usar un `JSONArray`, acceder a la clave `0` del mismo y entonces sí leerlo como un `JSONObject` normal.

Comment: gracias me fue de mucha ayuda